# Angular Cli - Not working bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I created Angular project using angular cli. I installed bootstrap using npm. But, it's not applying bootstrap styles without adding bootstrap css in index.html.

How to resolve this? I don't want to add bootstrap css manually.

Comment: are you using cli ?

Comment: Yes, I am using.

Comment: the answer by @wdanda is the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .angular-cli.json file:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```